# Best way to export scene objects to external program?

Tags: export, scene

Lets' say I have this scene:

[image]

The columns, floor, center pieces, etc., are all individual objects but all reside in the same Blender file. I wish to rebuild this scene in Unity3D, like I did here already:

[image]

I did this by saving the assembled scene in a blend file called "SceneAssembled". Then I would delete ALL objects EXCEPT the one I wants, say the pedestal in the middle. I would go File -> Save As "Pedestal", then I would close that file and re-open "SceneAssembled" and do that for every object, then re-assemble in Unity.

Is this a good way of doing this or are there better workflows?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any particular reason your are purposefully disassembling your scene then reassembling it again in Unity? What file format are you exporting to? Blender has for the most part an "export selected"  so you don't need to do that.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Unity supports .blend files, so he is trying to use that workflow (which is really difficult and buggy).

Comment: No reason part from the fact that I am completely new to Unity and Blender and have yet to learn what the "best" workflow is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export as an .fbx or .obj with "only selected" enabled...if you try to use .blend files in Unity you will run into all sorts of problems (bugs, only works if a compatible version of Blender is installed).

Select your objects that you want exported, then choose to export as .fbx or .obj. *FBX* supports animation, *OBJ* does not. If you just need a simple static mesh, you can use .obj, but I personally prefer to only use .fbx format for simplicity.

[image]

Finally, you don't need to export specific objects if you would rather not. If you need to export the entire scene (and will only want to export the entire scene in the future), just use this tool with all desired objects selected, and Unity will import it just fine. When it gets into Unity, the objects are still separate once you pull them into your scene...

Comment: But the textures are not exported?

Comment: @Black No, the textures cannot be exported. They are just images, so put the images in the game engine and build materials there...